# In knockout.js what is the difference between a viewmodel and a binding-context?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My interpretation is that a viewmodel is made up of a hierarchy of binding-contexts but I haven't been able to confirm this.  Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From [Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html):

> A binding context is an object that holds data that you can reference from your bindings. While applying bindings, Knockout automatically creates and manages a hierarchy of binding contexts. The root level of the hierarchy refers to the viewModel parameter you supplied to `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)`. Then, each time you use a control flow binding such as with or foreach, that creates a child binding context that refers to the nested view model data.

In other words, yes - a viewmodel used to apply bindings is the root of the hierarchy of binding contexts.